# Much info on web talks about the percents of fat in butter determine the flavor/aroma of its. Why does all ghee smell the same of nutty aroma?

Tags: butter, ghee

Do you think only the percents of fat helping to make flavor of butter? Do you think that "milk solid" contributes a major part in the flavor?

https://www.thehealthyjournal.com/faq/why-does-european-butter-taste-better

https://www.tasteofhome.com/article/your-complete-guide-to-butter/

Comment: I haven't seen a source that relates fat percentage and aroma. Maybe you can link one? There is a dubious marketing claim floating around that 3% more fat make for better pastry, but that's for textural reasons and has nothing to do with aroma and ghee.

Comment: Welcome to SA!  Jason, when you have additional information that clarifies the question you are asking, please add that information to the question itself (by editing it) instead of having it in comments.

Comment: Also, you seem to be asking multiple different and separate questions about the aroma and flavor of butter.  Please separate out your questions and ask one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Fat and mild solids together contributes to the flavor of butter.  When you make browned butter, the toasted mild solids contribute an even more nutty flavor.

Comment: What do you guess when many of the clarified butter made from different brands of Butter have similar in taste/flavor. I wonder that "milk solid and some aromatic oil" contributes a big role in taste/flavor. That is my assumption.

Comment: Do you think I am right if I say the flavor/taste of butter is decided by breed and food. I do not think all grass in somewhere is the same. Other weeds or flower weeds living beside grass decided a big part in building the flavor by having many kinds of weed on earth.

Comment: The diet of the animal that is the source of the butter most certainly has an influence on its flavor and aroma.

Comment: @moscafj that would be an ideal case. In current industrial practice, the diet is quite standardized, and the processing strips down the flavor of the product. I don't know if it is intentional or not, but packaged cow milk has less aroma than home-produced cow milk. I was once dismayed when I bought sheep yogurt and realized that it was so deodorized that I wouldn't have distinguished it from cow yogurt in a blind tasting. Butter has much subtler differences due to diet even with traditional production. With industrial production, I would call them imperceptible.

Comment: @rumtscho I agree...that doesn't change my comment above.